# Can I ask for help identifying design products?

Tags: discussion

Is this an appropriate place to ask for help identifying graphic design products? (e.g. web page designs, calendars, posters, etc)

Comment: What do you mean by "identifying graphic design products"? Do you mean if you see for example a plugin on a site, and you wonder what it is called? Or identifying for example the author of those pieces?

Comment: See the examples above. For example, suppose you had a picture of a poster and needed help identifying it (suppose also that google reverse image search gives nothing)

Comment: Its unlikely that this would work out

Comment: why don't you try a reverse image search?

Comment: I have tried; no luck.

Comment: Still not clear to me what you mean about "identifying" - do you mean _who_ made it, _how_ it was made, _what style/time/epoch_ it belongs to?

Answer (score 2):

I think Identifying a physical product or style is very acceptable.

Tha tags [terminology](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) and [style-identification](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style-identification) can be used for this. Say you saw a type of trade show display but didn't know a good way to search for it online. If you post an image and ask for help with the correct term to use, then I think its perfectly acceptable. As long as its a design related product of course. Even simple things might be taken for granted by some - there was a time when I didn't know tri-fold as an example. If I posted an image of one looking for the correct term, this seems okay to me.

I will say though - try to identify it on your own. Say what type of search phrases you used that turned up little or no results, otherwise it will be downvoted as poorly researched / lazy.

On the other hand, if you're asking for something specific like posting a single page out of a Hooters Girl's Calendar (sorry, it was the only well-known calendar I could think of) and asking us to identify which year and month it belonged to. This would not be okay. Or describing a vague idea of a logo or website and asking us to tell you what company or website it belongs to: again not okay.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think these types of questions would work very well within our community. Stack Exchange sites strive towards reusable knowledge; questions that are likely to help many are considered better than ones that only help an individual. It's difficult to imagine these types of questions going beyond a "single serving".

Comment: I think if its very specific it doesn't work... like font-id questions which should be closed already :P but broader questions can.